# Why am I getting socket.gaierror?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to access and show data from http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt . Here's my code:

```py
import socket         
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e', 80))  
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)    

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break       
    print(data.decode()) 
mysock.close()
```

I'm getting this error message :

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
```

I saw on another question that this means I do not have a valid host name, but I'm not sure why the host name is invalid.

Comment: `data.pr4e` is an invalid, did you mean `data.pr4e.org`? Also, the request

Comment: Also, you request is invalid, you should end it with `\r\n\r\n`, not `\n\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are passing the wrong host name to `connect()`. You need to change `'data.pr4e'` to `'data.pr4e.org'`.

Also, your request data is malformed, too. You need to remove the scheme and hostname from the request, and use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Try this:

```
import socket         
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))  
cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)    

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break       
    print(data.decode()) 
mysock.close()
```